# Search values in list with streaming api and keep search position (normalize measurement data)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I get lists of measurement data. An entry in this list contains a timstamp and the data itself. There is more or less for every 15min an entry - but there may also be missing data points or a big jitter.
What I need is to build a normalized list of data, where I have an entry for exact every 15min. As data, I can just take the previous measurement.

Input:

```
A    B         C     D  E                       F
|----|---------|-----|--|-----------------------|--> t
```

Output:

```
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|--> t
A    B    B    C    C    E    E    E    E    E    F
```

How can this be achieved in an elegant and efficient way with streams in java 8?
It cannot be a `data.stream().filter([...]).findFirst()` because there may be a lot of datapoints - searching always from beginning is too expensiv.
I made same tests with input data already aligned to 15min so that I was able to just do

```
public NormalizedData normalizeData(List<MeasurementData> data, Instant t) {
    return data.stream()
        .filter(d -> Objects.equals(d.getTimestamp().getEpochSecond(), t.getEpochSecond()))
        .map(d -> new NormalizedData(t, d))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(...);
}
```

for all `Instant t` which was too slow.

Any idea? We should be able to somehow store the search position in the stream and continue in the next turn. Or a completly different aproach.
If there is a solution with Third-Party stream-libraries compatible to standard streams (like `StreamEx`) this would also be an option.

Comment: have you tried running it in `.paralell()`?

Comment: This may improve the speed but not increase the efficiency.

Comment: When your data is sorted by timestamp, you can use binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is some sample code to show how you can achieve filling in the missing data points.

A lot of the code below is not required as it's just setting up data to show case how the code actually works.

What the code does is use the Stream API collect functionality and compare the last collected `DataPoint` with the current `DataPoint` and insert a new entry if the difference between there timestamps is greater than 15 minutes.

As you can see from the test data there is a 30 minute difference between C and D as well as E and F. This means data for C and E will be replicated.

***Code***

```
private static final long FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS = 900_000L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //This is just to get some realistic times
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<DataPoint> data = getDataPoints(now);

    ArrayList<DataPoint> newDataPoints = data.stream().collect(Collector.of(
            ArrayList<DataPoint>::new,
            (ArrayList<DataPoint> dataPoints, DataPoint nextDataPoint) -> {
                if (!dataPoints.isEmpty()) {
                    addPointIfRequired(dataPoints, nextDataPoint);
                }

                dataPoints.add(nextDataPoint);
            },
            (dataPoints, dataPoints2) -> {
                if (dataPoints.isEmpty()) return dataPoints2;

                if (!dataPoints2.isEmpty()) {
                    addPointIfRequired(dataPoints, dataPoints2.get(0));
                    dataPoints.addAll(dataPoints2);
                }

                return dataPoints;
            }
    ));

    newDataPoints.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static void addPointIfRequired(ArrayList<DataPoint> dataPoints, DataPoint nextDataPoint) {
    DataPoint previousDataPoint = dataPoints.get(dataPoints.size() - 1);
    long timestampDiff = nextDataPoint.timestamp - previousDataPoint.timestamp;

    if (timestampDiff > FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS) {
        long fifteenMinIncrement = previousDataPoint.timestamp + FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS;
        DataPoint newEntry = new DataPoint(previousDataPoint.data, fifteenMinIncrement);
        dataPoints.add(newEntry);
    }
}

private static List<DataPoint> getDataPoints(long now) {
    return Arrays.asList(
            //initial time
            new DataPoint("A", now),
            //15 minute increment
            new DataPoint("B", now + FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS),
            //15 minute increment
            new DataPoint("C", now + (FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS * 2)),
            //30 minute increment
            new DataPoint("D", now + (FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS * 4)),
            //15 minute increment
            new DataPoint("E", now + (FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS * 5)),
            //30 minute increment
            new DataPoint("F", now + (FIFTEEN_MINS_IN_MILLI_SECONDS * 7))
    );
}

private static class DataPoint {
    private final String data;
    private final long timestamp;

    private DataPoint(String data, long timestamp) {
        this.data = data;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data + " " + Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
    }
}
```

***Output***

```
A 2018-07-11T01:22:45.628Z
B 2018-07-11T01:37:45.628Z
C 2018-07-11T01:52:45.628Z
C 2018-07-11T02:07:45.628Z
D 2018-07-11T02:22:45.628Z
E 2018-07-11T02:37:45.628Z
E 2018-07-11T02:52:45.628Z
F 2018-07-11T03:07:45.628Z
```

Comment: You could simplify this by moving the `list.get(list.size() - 1)` into the `addPointIfRequired` method, as it will always use the last element of the target list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the try by [StreamEx](https://github.com/landawn/streamex) forked if I understand OP correctly:

```
// assume the data is sorted by time
final List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = N.asList(Pair.of(1, "A"), Pair.of(16, "B"), Pair.of(46, "C"),
    Pair.of(60, "D"), Pair.of(76, "E"), Pair.of(151, "F"));
final int startTime = data.get(0).left();
final int interval = 15;

final Map<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>> map = StreamEx.of(data).filter(p -> (p.left() - startTime) % interval == 0).toMap(p -> p.left());

IntStreamEx.rangeClosed(startTime, data.get(data.size() - 1).left(), interval) 
      .forEach(t -> map.computeIfAbsent(t, k -> Pair.of(t, map.get(t - interval).right())));

final List<Pair<Integer, String>> result = StreamEx.of(map).sortedBy(e -> e.getKey()).map(e -> e.getValue()).toList();

System.out.println(result.stream().map(p -> p.right).collect(Collectors.joining("--")));
```